# DataContractSerializerSettings Class Examples

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, xml-namespaces, datacontractserializer

I am looking for example on how to use the DataContractSerializerSettings class. There are two specific  properties I am interested in

1. RootName
2. RootNameSpace.

Can I use them in my code to set the namespace in the output xml?

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating the `DataContractSerializer`, then yes.  You can create a `DataContractSerializerSettings` object and set the `RootName` and/or `RootNamespace` using an `XmlDictionary` to create the `XmlDictionaryString`s.  Here's an example:

```
var settings = new DataContractSerializerSettings();
var xmlDictionary = new XmlDictionary();
settings.RootName = xmlDictionary.Add("MyRootName");
settings.RootNamespace = xmlDictionary.Add("MyNamespace");
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass), settings);
```

The name of the root element in the serialized XML will be "MyRootName" and the xmlns attribute will be "MyNamespace", for example:

```
<MyRootName xmlns:d1p1="MyDefaultNamespace" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="MyNamespace">
```

Note that the default namespace will still be included with the "d1p1" alias, so I don't think it's possible to override that namespace using these settings.  The easiest place to do that is wherever your class is defined using the `DataContract` attribute:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "MyDefaultNamespace")]
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing that adding the `[DataContract(Namespace = "...")]` to my class changes the `d1p1` namespace *prefix* - what I see it do is equivalent to the `settings.RootNamespace` line above; it changes the `value` of that prefix.